# how to hidden this form if user login to my site?

Tags: php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
     /// if you registered previuos and enter to this page go to admin.php
if (isset($_SESSION['uname']) and isset($_SESSION['pname'])) {
 //// i want to enter login and pass filed here to hidden

}

?>



                ///this is the form i want to be hidden if user login

  <form action="login.php" method="post" >
  <table width="171" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="97">
    <input class="put" name="uname"  type="text" size="10" />    </td>
    <td width="64" align="right" class="text_un">username</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input  type="password" size="10" name="password" /></td>
    <td align="right" class="text_pw">password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><input class="button" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="enter" /></td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </form>



<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: you question is not really concrete enough to give a good answer, you should maybe edit your question to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Oh you ninja you, give me a second to edit my answer...

**Edit2:** This should do it:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
     /// if you registered previuos and enter to this page go to admin.php
if (isset($_SESSION['uname']) and isset($_SESSION['pname'])) {
    //// i want to enter login and pass filed here to hidden

} else {

?>
<!-- form markup goes here -->

<?php

} // end the else statement.
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: you're not helping anyone help you.>>> because i still start learning php and all who help me strong knowledge with php and if not need to help thank you

Comment: i think, what he wants is optional hidden-inputs. see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset($_POST['password'] || !isset($_POST['uname']) {
?> <!-- closes the php block, so what follows is clean html -->
  <form action="login.php" method="post" >
  <table width="171" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="97">
    <input class="put" name="uname"  type="text" size="10" />    </td>
    <td width="64" align="right" class="text_un">username</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input  type="password" size="10" name="password" /></td>
    <td align="right" class="text_pw">password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><input class="button" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="enter" /></td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </form>
<?php /* re-opens the php */
} /* closes the 'if' */
else {
 /* do whatever you want, but the form won't be shown */
}
```

Please use some sanity-checking, validate the inputs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

this should do exactly what you want :)

```
ob_start();
session_start();
$hiddenFields = '';
     /// if you registered previuos and enter to this page go to admin.php
if (isset($_SESSION['uname']) and isset($_SESSION['pname'])) {
 //// i want to enter login and pass filed here to hidden

    $hiddenFields .= '<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="'. $_SESSION['uname'] .'" />';
    $hiddenFields .= '<input type="hidden" name="pname" value="'. $_SESSION['pname'] .'" />';
}

?>



                ///this is the form i want to be hidden if user login

  <form action="login.php" method="post" >
  <?php echo $hiddenFields ?>
  <table width="171" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="97">
    <input class="put" name="uname"  type="text" size="10" />    </td>
    <td width="64" align="right" class="text_un">username</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input  type="password" size="10" name="password" /></td>
    <td align="right" class="text_pw">password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top"><input class="button" type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="enter" /></td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: What is it that you think he wants, that the other answers didn't address?

Comment: he says "i want to enter login and pass filed here to hidden"